# decltype for method of templated template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class representing a TimeSeries of Data, since I did want to work as memory efficient as I could, I templated the class, so the stored data would only be as big as needed. But now I couldn't treat Data with different Base-Types the same, so I made a base class which had virtual versions of all methods of my actual class. That worked fine until the need for virtual template methods arised.
Which I could solve with typelists, but then I needed a virtual template method whith a dynamic return type. And I failed implementing that. I made a "minimal" example which show cases my problem. To me it seems the problem goes back to the decltype-statement in the std::result_of_t template, because my compiler states:

```
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'enable_if<_Test,_Ty>::type Base::analyze(CtorArgs...)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=result_of<unknown-type(const std::vector<TList::Head,std::allocator<TList::Head>> &,CtorArgs...)>::type
1>          ]
```

This error is quite far down the list, but seems to be the only explanation to me.
Here is the Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class TestAnalyzer
{
public:
    int analyze(const std::vector<T> &in, int a) { return a; }
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Typelist stuff, only in here so it compiles, but im 99% sure, this is not the problem
class null_type {};

template<typename H, typename T>
struct TypelistNode
{
    using Head = H;
    using Tail = T;
};

template<typename Head, typename ...Tail>
struct make_typelist
{
    using type = TypelistNode<
        Head,
        typename make_typelist<Tail...>::type
    >;
};

template<typename Last>
struct make_typelist<Last>
{
    using type = TypelistNode<Last, null_type>;
};

template<typename ... Types>
using Typelist = typename make_typelist<Types...>::type;

using SupportedTypes = Typelist<
    uint8_t, int8_t,
    uint16_t, int16_t,
    uint32_t, int32_t,
    uint64_t, int64_t,
    float, double>;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

class Base
{
public:
    //a few virtual methods here ...
    virtual ~Base() {}

    template<template <typename ...> class Analyzer, typename TList = SupportedTypes, typename ...CtorArgs>
    inline auto Base::analyze(CtorArgs ...)
        ->std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<TList, null_type>::value,
        std::result_of_t<decltype(&Analyzer<typename TList::Head>::analyze)(const std::vector<typename TList::Head>&, CtorArgs ...)>
        >;

    template<
        template<typename T> class Analyzer,
        typename TList = SupportedTypes,
        typename ...CtorArgs>
        auto analyze(CtorArgs ...)
        ->std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same<TList, null_type>::value,
        void>
    {
        throw std::logic_error("analyze was called with null_type");
    }
};

template <class T>
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    //implementations of virtuals here

    template<template<typename T> class Analyzer, typename ...Args>
    std::result_of_t<decltype(&Analyzer<T>::analyze)(Args...)>
        analyze(Args... args)
    {
        Analyzer<T> a;
        return a.apply(_data, args...);
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> _data;
};

template<template <typename ...> class Analyzer, typename TList, typename ...CtorArgs>
inline auto Base::analyze(CtorArgs ... args)
-> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<TList, null_type>::value,
    std::result_of_t<decltype(&Analyzer<typename TList::Head>::analyze)(const std::vector<typename TList::Head>&, CtorArgs ...)>
>
{
    if (auto *ptr = dynamic_cast<Derived<typename TList::Head>*>(this))
    {
        return ptr->analyze<Analyzer>(args...);
    }
    else
        return analyze<Analyzer, typename TList::Tail, CtorArgs ...>(args...);
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    Derived<int> MyObj;
    Base *ptr = &MyObj;
    std::cout << ptr->analyze<TestAnalyzer>(1);
    return 0;
}
```

So now the question is: what do I need to change to make this compile.

PS: I use VS2015

Comment: this looks like a really complicated program ;)
have you tried simplyfing it? maybe dont use that much templates? why do  you need the max memory efficiency?

Comment: Because I have a whole lot of Data (minutes to hours of recordings with samplerates of 12KHz), and this makes it possible to run this program on machines with 8GB Ram

Comment: ok. iam trying to compile the example with gcc, it gives some errors, related to the templates (shadowing params, result_of::type does not exist) but no sepcialization error. maybe it appears after the other errors are resolved.

Comment: another question: each data series is one type, right? And the analysis is done in a class. why does it need to be in a class? Is it possible to just overload the analysis function for each allowed type or sth like that?

Comment: because therer will be a lot of quite specific analysation methods, and I want to keep it seperated from the actual TimeSeries, because thats quite general

Comment: and the analyzers derive from each other do reuse functionality?